# Excel 2010 Formatting Challenge

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, cell-format, expansion, word-wrap

I am having **problems with cells not automatically expanding with wrapped text in Excel 2010.**

My rows contain simple formulas pulling data from another worksheet and the rows are formatted with Autofit Row Height.  The problem I am having is that the cells don't expand immediately.

I could easily toggle the "wrap text" button off and back on to make it work, but I have to protect the sheet so coworkers won't mess up the formulas; therefore, I am getting a lot of calls to help troubleshoot the problem.  ***The strange thing is that if I save the file, exit it and reopen the file, the cells adjust appropriately to accommodate the wrapped text without doing anything else.*** This would suggest that the formatting is correct. **What do I need to do make this happen immediately so I can avoid having to exit and reopen the file just to make it work after importing the data?**

Things I have considered and tried are the following:

1. I have deleted the formulas and simply copied and pasted the text from the other worksheet and the rows/cells expand appropriately at the time I paste the text.  Again, suggesting that I have it formatted correctly
2. I have considered any potential merged cells that might be causing conflicts and there are none.
3. I have deleted the rows and reentered the formulas to try and eliminate any potential conflicts from where I might have manually formatted the rows beforehand.
4. I have tried resizing the cells by mousing over the dividers for the rows and double-clicking to adjust the row heights with no success. They will adjust, but it doesn't effect or improve the auto expansion with future entries.

Its about to drive me crazy and I welcome any ideas.  I'm sure there may be a way to accomplish this with macros and/or Visual Basic programming, but that is above my skill level.

Comment: Too early in the morning for me to test now, but check out the macro provided on the [Contextures Blog](http://blog.contextures.com/archives/2012/06/07/autofit-merged-cell-row-height/), and specifically the addition by Ged Warren for values updated from another sheet.

Comment: Thanks!  Unfortunately, I don't know enough about VBA to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

AutoFit for Row Height applies to the font size, the number of lines of wrapped text has no bearing. (This is a clue that Excel isn't intended as a word processor :-))